# Migrate React version

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any tool that would help me to migrate any React version to another? Something like [React Native Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper) but for React.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is really required for React. Unlike React Native there are no gradle or podfiles. The process is much simpler.

Just run `npm i react react-dom react-scripts` or `yarn add react react-dom react-scripts` to get the latest version of React and react-scripts (if you are using that).

If you are using Typescript you might want to update `@types/react` too.

Some other packages might need updating but this will be a similar flow to updating other packages with React Native that is not covered by the update helper.

You can run [`npm outdated`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-outdated) or [`yarn outdated`](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/outdated/) to see any available package updates.

### React 17

React 17 had a some [specific update requirements that you can read about here.](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/10/20/react-v17.html#installation)